# Tizen SDK TV Icon

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-tv

I am currently building an application for commercial use, but I want to be sure my Icon loos correct in the My Apps screen on the television. As of know I only see the default developer icon. I have replace the icon with my own in my project. I co see Icon in the recent pop up menu, but it is missing from My Apps. In the attachment IMG_2834.jpg has the black icon which is ok, but IMG_2835.JPG is the basic default Icon. Well I dont want that I would like to see my Icon on this screen.
[image: Generic Screen Icon]

[image: Recent Applications]

Comment: Samsung TV icon guidelines can be found in http://developer.samsung.com/tv/design/app-icons-and-screenshots/

Comment: @Kiran how does it work exactly, you create those images and simply drop them into the root of the bundle and it works? 'cause I do not see any related fields in the config, where I could reference them.

Comment: As far as I remember, your development package will contain only one icon. The screenshots and backgrounds you will have to upload while submitting your application to the seller office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please check these Articles, They mentioned 'In order for application icons to display on the Samsung Apps screen must comply with the conditions given...'

[Creating and Registering App Icons](https://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/02_samsung_applications.html)

[Creating and registering App Icons and Screenshots](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenUxGuide/02/02_samsung_applications.html#ux-02)

Comment: @Armaan-Ul-Islam both links are outdated as of now.

Comment: @thechrisberry did you solve it, maybe you could update your question/response with the solution?